# Building a search engine in java

Tags: java

I am building a search engine in Java. The search engine should search for the word entered in the textbox in 80 documents and then display the number of matching documents, the number of times that word appearing in each document.

For a start I imported all txt files and created a class Search.

I need to build an index in order to index each word in the 80 documents so that I can develop an algorithm to compare the word entered with the indexed words and return back the results.

Any suggestions for a start would be grateful !!

Regards,

Humam.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Any suggestions for a start would be grateful!

Absolutely - [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html):

> Apache Lucene(TM) is a high-performance, full-featured text search engine library written entirely in Java. It is a technology suitable for nearly any application that requires full-text search, especially cross-platform.

Comment: @TedHopp Where did anyone say anything about Android in this post?

Comment: @Hunter - I had been reading a bunch of Android posts and still had that on my mind. When I realized my mistake, I deleted my comment, hoping nobody had seen it. Obviously I was too late. :)

Comment: Other search engines worth a look are [Minion](http://minion.java.net/) (from Oracle Labs) and [egothor](http://www.egothor.org/).

Comment: Also take a look at [elastic-search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) it is a distributed search server built on top of Lucene that provides you with features such as sharding and replication.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [FTS capabilities of SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html). That should do pretty much what you want.

Comment: I am reading the text files directly from memory. I am not using any databases. Just a thought, how can I use a multi-dimensional array to store all the words as an index ?

Comment: Take a look at using a HashMap, with the target words as the keys and an array of word counts/document as the values. This will only be practical if there isn't too much data and if a simple equality test is enough for locating words.